# How to run shell expressions in current frame in Pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, ipdb

In Pycharm, when you run a test in a debug mode, you can stop it at breakpoint and see the expressions, or even validate some of them, but is there a way to run arbitrary expression in a shell, like you can normally do in IPDB?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/evaluating-expressions.html

Comment: I did see this, but hoped there's something like a usual shell. Thanks anyway!